# href doesn't work on Drop Down with bootstrap 4 (SOLVED)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I made a drop-down menu with bootstrap 4 and also change it into hover. Everything works great,  but I cannot link properly through the href.

When I click "PRODUCTS", it doesn't switch to third.html.
How can I fix it?
[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188228/20327789)

Also, how to remove the original click action since I already have the hover one?
[SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817233/20327789)

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./second.html">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="./third.html"
              id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              PRODUCTS
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ch1">A</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ch2">B</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#ch3">C</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./fourth.html">EQUIPMENT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./fifth.html">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you the file ./third.html exists ?

Comment: @Floxblah  Yes, it exist.

Comment: See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117329/bootstrap-collapsible-sidebar-clickable-top-level-button) question.

Comment: @Cervuscamelopardalis thanks for the detailed reply! It works, I also found an [easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188228/20327789) to achieve this. Anyway, thanks for your kindness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved the problem.